# Encryption in Angular Crypto-JS and Decryption in PHP & Vice Versa

Tags: php, angular, cryptojs

I am trying to implement the encryption and decryption in angular 11 crypto-js(browser level) and PHP(server level).

**Randomly Generated Key and Iv.**

Used this key and iv in both angular and php for doing the encryption and decryption.

```
Key - 46d7093c56d9079406754989716a402d
Iv - df9fa46af13e5921
```

**Angular CryptoJS Encryption**

```
let msg = "Testing";
let configuration = {
  keySize: 128 / 8,
  iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),                                                                                                  
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
};
let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key, configuration).toString(); //U2FsdGVkX1+A5bM0Y4epRBtB/A2KYdupCgZXmSSu3hQ=
```

**Angular CryptoJS Decryption**

```
let encrypted = "U2FsdGVkX1+A5bM0Y4epRBtB/A2KYdupCgZXmSSu3hQ=";
let configuration = {
  keySize: 128 / 8,
  iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),                                                                                                  
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
};
let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, configuration).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

**PHP Encryption for CryptoJS**

```
$Message = "Testing";

$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($Message, 'AES-128-CBC', $Key, 0, $Iv); #CC06me/4GIHVnoxdYgGTAQ==
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($Message, 'AES-256-CBC', $Key, 0, $Iv); #cgWrkf8HfdDJg0VybavncQ==
```

**PHP Decryption for CryptoJS**

```
$Key = "46d7093c56d9079406754989716a402d";
$Iv = "df9fa46af13e5921";
$Encrypted = "CC06me/4GIHVnoxdYgGTAQ==";
$encrypted = openssl_decrypt($Encrypted, 'AES-128-CBC', $Key, 0, $Iv);
$Encrypted = "cgWrkf8HfdDJg0VybavncQ==";
$encrypted = openssl_decrypt($Message, 'AES-256-CBC', $Key, 0, $Iv);
```

The encryption which is made by angular cryptojs is able to decrypt by angular cryptojs, but not in php. I tried multiple module to make the decryption in PHP, but I am unable to decrypt the same.

Can anyone please suggest what I am missing in this method of decryption.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you try to add zero padding: 
```let configuration = {
  keySize: 128 / 8,
  iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
   padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding,                                                                                       
  mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
};```

Comment: I added the Zero Padding in CryptoJS and OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING in php, some junk value is getting during decryption.

Comment: can you try to do not' add OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING in php

Comment: I tried that also like the code of PHP in question, but decryption result is empty.

Comment: The problem is not caused by the padding, both codes use (by default) PKCS#7.

Comment: The problem is rather caused since in the CryptoJS code `key` is interpreted as passphrase because it's passed as a string. You have to pass the key as `WordArray`. For AES-256 you can use the Utf8 encoder (analog to the IV).

Comment: After adding WordArray to key, the encryption is able to parse in PHP. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: What a guessing game. Can you please provide reference why it should even work?